# How to add "Harvard-Angelia" Reference Style on Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I downloaded Microsoft Office 2010 using PlayOnLinux. I checked the reference style there and "Harvard-Angelia" was missing. I downloaded the reference style on .ens form but am confused on where to place that file on.

Comment: Here are printed instructions: https://mrproofread.com/content/how-add-harvard-referencing-word and here is video instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19-E1OCdvbY

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix but the website specifed above doesn't include instructions for ubuntu. I couldn't find single folder labeled "bibliography" or ''styles"

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to do it through following steps:

Download "Harvard-Angelia" in .xml file from following website:

https://github.com/codingo/BibWord/blob/master/styles/HarvardAnglia.XSL

access the "Open the dictionary" tab of the MS Word on PlayOnLinux located in    the left side. go to bibliography/style and paste the downloaded .xml file in there. Rerunning MS Word.